# Replicaing some exsheets features in xsim

Tags: exsheets, xsim

My `exsheets` templates no longer compile after a recent LaTeX update and so I thought that rather than downgrading TeX, it might be better just upgrade my templates. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to extract the information I want from the manual.

I have two things I am trying to achieve.

1. What is the new version of the `\PrintSolutionsF{}` command? I use this to have hand-in-dates on homework which I hand out, but not on the model solutions. I would have guess that `\IfSolutionPrintF{}` is the follow up, but this only seems to work inside template environments and not inside normal text.
2. I want my questions to be numbered, but not the solutions, because I place each solution immediately after its corresponding question. The code in `exsheets` for this was:

   ```
   \DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-no-nr}{default}{
     attach = {
       main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
       main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
     }
   }
   \RenewQuSolPair
     {question}[headings=block-subtitle]
     {solution}[headings=block-no-nr]
   ```

What would be the corresponding code for `xsim`?

Edit: The following ought to be a minimal working example of my old `exsheets` templates, but I can't confirm this, because I can no longer compile my `exsheets` files. I cannot provide compilable code for `xsim`, because I that is what I'm seeking help for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}


% Questions numbered but solutions not numbered
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-no-nr}{default}{
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  }
}
\RenewQuSolPair
  {question}[headings=block-subtitle]
  {solution}[headings=block-no-nr]

% True to show solutions or comment out/false to hide solutions
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\begin{document}
%%%Title. Shows due date when not showing solutions%%%%%%%
\hrule\vspace{1mm}
{\bf \PrintSolutionsF{Exercise Sheet No X}
  \PrintSolutionsT{Model Solutions Sheet No X} for
  XXXX \PrintSolutionsF{\ \\Due XX.XX.XXXX}}
\hrule
\vspace{5mm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{question}
  This is a sample numbered question.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  This is an unnumbered sample solution.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your code fully compilable.

Comment: @naphaneal I've attempted to give a minimal working example of my old exsheets code.

Comment: @clemens Thank you for improving the presentation of my question.

Comment: The question actually was clear even without a MWE… I added my answer before the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined test if the solutions are printed because `xsim` allows different kind of exercise types each with their own set of solutions. But it is possible to define a command which checks the default type (called `exercise`):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand \ifprintsolution [2]
  { \xsim_if_solution_print:nTF {exercise} {#1} {#2} }  
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In order to have unnumbered solutions you need to define a template first. This would do:

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{no-number}
  {\subsection*{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}}}
  {}
```

You can now use it with `\xsimsetup{solution/template = no-number}`.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand \ifprintsolution [2]
  { \xsim_if_solution_print:nTF {exercise} {#1} {#2} }  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\handindate[1]{%
  \ifprintsolution{}{This homework is due #1.}%
}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{no-number}
  {\subsection*{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}}}
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  solution/template = no-number ,
  % uncomment to see the unnumbered solution (and have the hand-in date
  % disappear):
  % solution/print = true
}

\begin{document}

\handindate{6.\@ of December 2019}

\begin{exercise}
  some exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  the solution
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Without...

[image]

... or with solutions

[image]

Comment: @clements This works! Thank you very much!